# Kali Linux libpython2.7 and python-tk incompatibilities when trying to install a python2 package

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, python

Hi i am trying to install `apparmor-utils`. when i type

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

I get this following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7-stdlib : Breaks: python-tk (< 2.7.14~rc1-1~) but 2.7.13-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I am running linux kali on windows virtualbox
**Kali Rolling (2017.1) x64
2017-04-24**

Comment: Does `sudo apt update` succeed? and if so, what's the result of then typing ` sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`.

Comment: sudo apt update runs successfully and get a message saying
2052 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
when i try sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
i get the error like in my question

Please have a look at this screenshot 
https://prnt.sc/wbgb6l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently in Kali Linux, `apparmor-utils` is a python2 package. Python2 is unsupported now, and by proxy probably that package. For reference the [`apparmor`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/apparmor) and [`apparmor-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/apparmor-utils) package in upstream Debian is now python3, in stable. So Kali is apparently lagging behind Debian Stable (which does not bode well for anyone using it).

It seems Kali still contains (but not maintains) a python2 variant of `apparmor-utils`. That's what you're trying to install. You can see from [their repo](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/a/apparmor/) that they have a `python3-apparmor`; however, they do not have a python3 `apparmor-utils` that I can see. Moreover, it seems that their python2 packages `libpython2.7-stdlib` and `python-tk` are incompatible, this will prevent the installation of anything that requires both of them (like `apparmor-utils`).

So your solution here is simple, stop using Kali. Like always, it's poorly maintained. Check out Debian upstream and just add the packages you want.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. im moving to ubuntu now

Comment: @Shuhadzaman I do believe you'll learn more about Linux and be pleasantly surprised. Enjoy the journey. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if we're done here.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the broken packages.

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep ^iU | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo dpkg --purge
   ```
2. Fix broken packages.

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```
3. Update the list of available software.

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. Remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies changed or the package(s) needing them were removed in the meantime.

   ```
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
5. Run `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils` again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but my term.log file is empty

Comment: @Shuhadzaman not sure what that has to do with anything...